# How do I get file name of the file currently being tested by rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rake task if I want to know the name of the file when that file is picked up for testing then how do I do that. Reason is that some of the files produce warning. I am not sure which of my 800 tests is producing warning.

My rake task is something like this. I am using rails3.

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test_hr_module) do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'

  t.test_files = Dir.glob('test/{hr}/**/*_test.rb').sort

  t.warning = true
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always call single files:

```
ruby test/unit/model_test.rb
```

You can even use the name flag to only run specific tests

```
ruby test/unit/model_test.rb -n test_name
```

You'll probably need to change `require 'test_helper'` to `require 'test/test_helper'` in the test file though.

If you really need to do this in a rake task could you try:

```
Dir.glob('test/**/*_test.rb').each do |f|
  puts `ruby #{f}`
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the pseudo-variable `__FILE__` to achieve this?

Comment: In future use backticks rather than the pre tag to stop automatic escaping.